# Attaching Curtain Rod To Thin Plastic

Tags: plastic

What could I use to attach a curtain rod in my RV. The backing is plastic about 1/8 inch thick. Behind that is about 1". The shortest toggle bolt I can find is 2". Drywall anchors are not working.

Comment: You've got a layer of something, then 1/8" plastic, and then a 1" empty cavity? Is that right? What's the first layer?

Comment: Weight of the curtain?  If no ankle biters togging on it, maybe adhesive/glue will work if curtain not heavy.

Comment: `Behind that is about 1".` ... 1" of what?

Comment: I assume its a 1 inch cavity to external wall.

Comment: Hi Randy, look around for toggle with small wings, the screw length is irrelevant as you can cut it.  [Have a look here](https://www.fastenersuperstore.com/products/toggle-bolts).  Better still walk in to a hardware store yourself and ask the attendant.  Otherwise Command Strips will work.  Buy one and try a pull test on the plastic wall.